Find the feasible solutions of a minimal path set of vectors
Finding the feasible solutions for vectors representing minimum paths based on the mathematical basis:

First example

I need to create the constraints according to equations (1) and (2) above:
ee={e[1],e[2],e[3],e[4],e[5],e[6]};
M={3,2,1,1,1,2};
mpp={mp[1],mp[2],mp[3],mp[4]};
ff={f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4]};
L={2,1,1,1};
mp[1]={e[1],e[5]};
mp[2]={e[2],e[6]};
mp[3]={e[1],e[3],e[6]};
mp[4]={e[2],e[4],e[5]};

My attempt
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[1]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[2]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[3]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[4]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[5]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]
Total[Table[If[MemberQ[mp[i], e[6]], f[i], 0], {i, 4}]]

My problem is to find a programming formula to configure these constraints according to the theoretical aspect equations (1) and (2) above.
I have tried many functions and I have not got a suitable idea about creating a suitable code to solve such questions.
Please help... Thank you very much

Your notations do not match the ones in the picture, and your code does not run. Please explain your problem further, especially the meaning of the notations in the picture.

@houzw I will edit the question and explain the problem more clearly.

@houzw I modified the question.

f={f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4]} causes an error. Please correct.

@A.Kato It is possible to change the notation, but I have no idea how to write code for the inequality (1) and (2).

@A.Kato Do you mean changing the symbol (f) to another letter?

That is one possibilty. Another is to use list of substitution rules. People want : More easy-to-understand meaning of your problem, in terms of standard words, e.g. graphs, vectors, etc, rather than equations. For example, you mention path or vectors in the title, but no explanation in the body.  People also want to know "What Mathematica code you have tried?"

Not sure if this is what you need.
Clear["`*"]
M = {3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2};
L = {2, 1, 1, 1};
mp[1] = {e[1], e[5]};
mp[2] = {e[2], e[6]};
mp[3] = {e[1], e[3], e[6]};
mp[4] = {e[2], e[4], e[5]};
element[a_, list_?ListQ] := Or @@ ((a == # &) /@ list)
Table[Table[
   If[element[e[i], mp[j]], f[j], Nothing, Nothing], {j, 1, 4}], {i, 
   1, 6}] // 
 Table[If[Length[#[[i]]] == 1, 0 <= #[[i, 1]] <= L[[#[[i, 1, 1]]]], 
    0 <= Total[#[[i]]] <= M[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[#]}] &

(*{0\[LessEqual]f[1]+f[3]\[LessEqual]3,0\[LessEqual]f[2]+f[4]\
\[LessEqual]2,0\[LessEqual]f[3]\[LessEqual]1,0\[LessEqual]f[4]\
\[LessEqual]1,0\[LessEqual]f[1]+f[4]\[LessEqual]1,0\[LessEqual]f[2]+f[\
3]\[LessEqual]2}*)


